# Can winform C# applications run from citrix?

Tags: citrix

Can winform C# applications run from citrix?

If the application is kept on Citrix server, can it be viewed in windows OS machines?

Will the same be viewable via iPad?

-Karthick

Answer (score 4):

The only real issue I've seen with home-grown .Net apps on Citrix is the occasional problem with [code access security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Yes to all of your questions.

1. Winform applications can be written in C# and run on Citrix
2. Once you publish the application it can be run on windows OS via the Citrix client. It will appear that the app is running locally.
3. Right now there is a client for the iPad available in the app store. Using this you should be able to connect to your apps via Citrix

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it wouldn't run on Citrix. If the corresponding framework is installed on the Citrix servers, it will run on it.

I don't know about iPad, since I believe it has to be from the App Store, but maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Of course yes to all of your questions, Citrix is only an environment.